# Multi-line argument help line in ArgumentParser in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a code which takes some arguments as follow:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
requiredNamed = parser.add_argument_group('required named arguments')
requiredNamed.add_argument('--input_feed', help='''Please provide an input csv file for automatic database creation such as follow: \n environment, database_name, location \n
 ENV, d_wc_wrk_pic, '/data/dev/wc/storage/work/d_wc_wrk_pic'
 ''',required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

The output on stdout is as follow:

[stdout output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7drkF.jpg)

when I type the --help command the hints are not followed by new lines? can any one suggest me a way to fix this new line error?

Answer (score 0):

In the `argparse` module, there is a method in the class HelpFormatter:

```
def _split_lines(self, text, width):
    text = self._whitespace_matcher.sub(' ', text).strip()
    # The textwrap module is used only for formatting help.
    # Delay its import for speeding up the common usage of argparse.
    import textwrap
    return textwrap.wrap(text, width)
```

Although your help message includes new lines, but the `_split_lines` method replaces them into spaces, and then split lines again using the `textwrap` module.

To avoid directly modify the code of the `argparse` moudle, you can use a trick called injection:

```
import argparse


def inject_help_formatter():
    def _my_split_lines(self, text, width):
        return text.split('\n')

    # Inject
    argparse.HelpFormatter._split_lines = _my_split_lines

# Do inject before `parser.parse_args()`
inject_help_formatter()

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
requiredNamed = parser.add_argument_group('required named arguments')
requiredNamed.add_argument('--input_feed', help='''Please provide an input csv file for automatic database creation such as follow: 
environment, database_name, location
 ENV, d_wc_wrk_pic, '/data/dev/wc/storage/work/d_wc_wrk_pic'
 ''', required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

`--help` outputs:

```
optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit

required named arguments:
  --input_feed INPUT_FEED
                        Please provide an input csv file for automatic database creation such as follow: 
                        environment, database_name, location
                         ENV, d_wc_wrk_pic, '/data/dev/wc/storage/work/d_wc_wrk_pic'
```